# What is better more efficient for a k,v loop?

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua, roblox

I am currently writing a game code on the roblox platform.

This used to be my previous method

```lua
for i,v in pairs(object:GetDescendants()) do
 -- do stuff if v:IsA("etcetc")
end
```

but since i've read that object references stay in a table and don't get cleaned by the memory I thought I may manually have to do this

```lua
local reference = obj:GetDescendants()
for i,v in pairs(reference) do
 -- code if v:isa etc etc etc
end
table.clear(reference) -- sets all to nil
-- reference becomes nil at end of scope
```

What exactly goes on in the memory of a for i, v in pairs(table) loop?

I know that lua compiles into C and i've been trying to work hard on the memory of my game

I know that the function for loop is itself a function where the argument is a reference to that table.

so it makes sense to set that table to nil via another reference outside. idk

Comment: "I know that lua compiles into C" not sure where you heard that, because its definitely wrong. It's interpreted.

Comment: "but since i've read that object references stay in a table and don't get cleaned by the memory" If the table that the object references are in isn't reachable, it and all of its values will get freed by the garbage collector. Running `table.clear` on a table that is about to have all its references go away is extra work for no reason.

Comment: If `object:GetDescendants()` is a list you can use a numeric for loop or `ipairs` to speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

A table gets collected if the last reference, even in package.loaded, is gone.

```
cg_tab = setmetatable({}, -- Construct
{__gc = function(tab) -- Triggered at: collectgarbage()
    print("Resurrected " .. tostring(tab))
end})

cg_tab = {} -- Destroying with new reference (Construct)

collectgarbage() -- Collect
-- Output: Resurrected table: 0x7fad23b800
```

So imagine a table is holding tables and other datatypes.
They all have to wait to be collected.
After collecting their used memory is freed.